# How to specify mathematical formula for "falling" in a center

Tags: graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

Okay, I know the title is a bit odd so I'll try to describe it in more detail here.

I would like to plot a polar graph using following conditions (let $\phi$ be some known angle $0 \le \phi \le 2\pi$ radians which we know):

- for this particular $\phi$ distance to center is known. We know $r(\phi)$.
- $r(0)=0$
- tangent angle for polar graph at angle $\phi$ is also known. We know $dx/dy (\phi)$

I would like to get polar equation that fits above criteria.

I've managed to do this for polar graph of type $r(\theta)=a(\theta)^b$. To be more precise I managed to specify $a$ and $b$ to conform to conditions specified earlier. But the problem is this formula is only good for certain conditions (if $b<0$ then for this polar graph $r(0)$ is not $0$).

I would like for this polar graph (equation) to be some kind of spiral.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you want $b \gt 0$.  Then you get a logarithmic spiral.  The constant $a$ will rotate the spiral around the origin, $b$ will determine how tight it is.  What is your question?

Comment: My question is what parameters should be so that above three conditions are met. It can be logarithmic spiral or any other spiral. I would like to get an equation of such spiral.

Comment: And btw., you don't get logarithmic spiral which is really $r(\theta)=a e^b \theta$ where $\theta$ is in exponent.

Comment: Yes, I confused myself about the logartihmic spiral.  MathJax hint:  for multicharacter exponents, put them in braces, so e^{b\theta} gives $e^{b\theta}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a logarithmic spiral the angle between the spiral and the circle is constant.  For $r=ae^{b\theta}$ the angle is $\frac \pi 2-\arctan \frac 1b$.  You can convert your desired slope at angle $\phi$ to an angle and use that to find $b$.  The below figure has the spiral $r=e^{\theta/5}$ and shows the circle at the radius corresponding to about $\frac {5\pi}4$.  It also sketches the tangent line at that point.  The angle between the circle and the tangent is $\frac \pi 2 - \arctan 5 \approx 12^\circ$.  This would suggest the angle between the tangent and the horizontal axis is about $-57^\circ$.

[image]